# Export WP database for import using WP-CLI on Vagrant Box

Tags: database, import, export, bulk-import, wp-cli

#### Problem

Now that I have a new environment with [WP-CLI `db`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/db/) [`import`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/db/import/) / [`export`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/db/export/) I need to import a database from a website that never had WP-CLI installed.

#### Question

What's the best Non-WP-CLI export method for WP-CLI import?

---

Backstory: I've been using [Basic WordPress Vagrant Environment](https://github.com/ideasonpurpose/basic-wordpress-vagrant) for local testing and recently the author added [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org). The more I've been playing around with it the more I'm in love.  I even went so far as to create a [bash script](https://codepad.co/snippet/x9TwyHwH) to spin up new [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com) boxes using just a name.

---

Is it better to do an export in WXR format through the WordPress [export panel](https://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen) or [script](https://codepad.co/snippet/NEToo4Kz) then use WP-CLI's [`import`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/import/)?

```
require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/export.php';

// Buffer output
ob_start();

// Generates the WXR export file for download.
$defaults = array (
    'content'    => 'all', 'author' => false, 'category' => false,
    'start_date' => false, 'end_date' => false, 'status' => false,
);

export_wp( $defaults );

// Get the buffer contents
$xml_export_data = ob_get_clean();
echo $xml_export_data;
```

Or is there a similar way like above, that I can leverage the WP-CLI [db export code](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/master/php/commands/db.php#L114) and produce a file ready to be [imported](http://wp-cli.org/commands/db/import/).

```
$ wp db export /vagrant/site/site_export.sql
Success: Exported to /vagrant/site/site_export.sql
```

The easiest route for my main (most important server) is to just do a [mysqldump](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/) directly through SSH.

```
# backup:
mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql

# restore:
mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
```

I'm just not sure that the regular SQL dump will hold all the values required for a WP-CLI import.

---

### Update

A simple `mysqldump` could be the only thing needed. Now I'm thinking I should have transferred over all the files before import... I'll keep ya'll posted but this could be a two-line process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### THE SHORT

**Export**

`sudo mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD DBNAME > filename.sql`

**Import**

`wp db import filename.sql`

---

### THE LONG

So this turns out to be very painless. The server dump is exactly what [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/commands/db/) needs to [import](http://wp-cli.org/commands/db/import/).

**REMOTE**

1. `sudo mkdir backup`

   - Make a directory for the file.
2. `sudo chown -f -R ec2-user:group backup`

   - Set permissions to the directory for my SSH user.
3. `cd backup`

   - Enter the directoy
4. Run `sudo mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD DBNAME > filename.sql`

   - Initially I was getting permission errors and that was because my EC2-USER needed control of the output directory.

**LOCAL**

5. Download `filename.sql` to my Vagrant folder
6. `vagrant ssh`

   - into the box for WP-CLI access
7. `wp db import /vagrant/filename.sql`
8. `wp search-replace old-site.com new-site.dev --test-run`

   - Test the operation first
9. `wp search-replace old-site.com new-site.dev`

---

### NOTES

- Make sure plugins and themes are in the correct directories
- Any errors in your PHP code will break the WP-CLI since it loads WP
- WP Codex [recommends](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) to not change the GUID. You can skip the GUID in search and replace with `wp search-replace 'http://example.dev' 'http://example.com' --skip-columns=guid`